# C# Multi thread add to a list

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to use Multi-thread to add new elements to a list.

I know this is no a good idea, i just looking for something like this.

I will only need to add new , no change any existed element.

Comment: See the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace. you can find something useful.

Comment: Why do you think it would be a bad idea? And there's plenty of examples on the Internet. If you have a specific problem, please show your code and what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

`List` is not designed to be accessed from multiple threads at the same time.  You cannot have more than one thread adding items concurrently.  Attempting to do so can result in the entire list becoming corrupted, which could result in exceptions, items being skipped, new data you never added, or other types of undefined behavior.

Consider using a data structure from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace, such as a `BlockingCollection` with a `ConcurrentQueue` or `ConcurrentBag` if you want to be generating objects to add to a collection from multiple threads concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Thread-Safe collection to do this. Look at `ConcurrentQueue<T>` or `ConcurrentBag<T>` or `BlockingCollection<T>` (for ProducerConsumer)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx